# How does fire spread on a piece of paper?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

If one lights the corner of a piece of paper with a match, the fire gradually spreads. What equation can be used to predict how the fire is going to spread  spatially and temporally? At first, I thought thermodynamics would give answer to this question. But as far as I know, thermodynamics does not say anything about the dynamics of a system. So, how to tackle this question?

Comment: Are you looking for an empirical solution or an ivory tower purist equation.  Navier-stokes is probably the dominant force in fire burning, but fire is a tremendously complicated process.

Comment: I am looking for a quantitative solution of the problem. If you give an idea how to approach the problem using Navier Stokes equation, that will be ok.

Comment: Are you looking to be able to use it to predict a burn, or are you just looking to know what makes the fire "tick?"

Comment: To predict a burn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a simple expression for the speed of the spread, I can think of an easy way to simulate the problem that should give you the answer. We assume the paper is lying horizontally on a table, so that gravitation and convection can be neglected.

Quantities needed:

- $\kappa$: thermal conductivity of paper
- $E_B$: Total energy released from burning a given mass of paper
- $\rho$: density of paper
- $\ell$: thickness of paper
- $t_B$: time it takes to burn a small square of paper
- $T_c$: temperature at which paper burns
- $C$: specific heat of paper
- $\sigma$: Stefan-Boltzmann constant

Paper burns when it reaches temperature $T_c$. The temperature distribution is determined by the heat equation with a source:

$\frac{dT}{dt}=\kappa\nabla^2 T + \frac{Q}{C\rho}$

So we'll divide our paper into tiny area elements of area $A$, and set boundary conditions to be $T_c$ for one of the corners and room temperature for the rest of the border. Initial conditions should be room temperature everywhere except for the corner that's already at $T_c$. Additionally, for each area element, assign a "burn-time" counter, setting all counters initially to zero.

Suppose we choose a time step $\Delta t$.

For each area element, calculate the increment in temperature over the time step according to the heat equation, using the usual numerical methods to handle the Laplacian. As for the handling of the $Q$ term, if the element's temperature is above $T_c$ and its "burn-time" counter is below $t_B$, then set $Q=E_B\rho \ell A\frac{\Delta t}{t_B}+\sigma A T^4\Delta t$ and increment the "burn-time" counter by $\Delta t$. Otherwise, $Q=\sigma A T^4 \Delta t$.

This should generate a reasonably realistic simulation of burning paper. I accounted for the fact that a burning area element should produce heat, but also should eventually burn out, not producing heat anymore (hence the "burn-time" counter). I assumed the power output of the combustion reaction was constant during burning, which is probably inaccurate, but anything more precise is beyond my expertise. Because of the boundary conditions, the simulation will be most accurate in the center, or for large pieces of paper.

Comment: In some cases, I have seen that spread of burning crucially depends on the initial tick caused by a match. Even if I try to start the burning  similarly (though I was doing it manually) fire spreads differently. Do you think your model can account for that?

Comment: Probably. Only one way to find out!

Comment: You'll need to know about air currents in the vicinity of the burn as well as the orientation of the paper to account for gravity. Yes, gravity affects the burn.

Comment: This seems like a good example where "simple expression" + "easy way" = "completely wrong". For example you haven't considered *radiative* heat transfer between different parts of the burning system. In fact it's not clear you have even considered *convective* heat transfer either. The idea that the paper heats up only because of conduction is somewhere close to being "not even wrong," to misuse Heisenberg's comment.

Comment: " Only one way to find out" - since your model doesn't include gravitational effects (such as the effect of buoyancy forces on the hot gas flow) it would presumably predict that a vertical sheet of paper would burn identically from top-to-bottom and from bottom-to-top. If you have ever tried to light a real fire, that is obviously not the case!

Comment: @alephzero Well, if the paper is lying flat on a table, in a large, well-ventilated room (not altogether unreasonable assumptions), then convective heat transfer between adjacent area elements doesn't really play a role, as the air mainly goes upward and away from the paper, and radiative transfer between adjacent area elements is negligible. I've edited the answer to include radiative heat loss, but since the fluid temperature and the burning paper temperature are similar, convective losses are negligible; are you happy now?

Comment: @alephzero Lying flat on the table, there are no gravitational effects other than suppressing convective heat transfer across area elements, which improves my model. And yes, I have edited my answer to stipulate that this is really only for paper lying flat on a table.